# How to insert variable into Django template and test whole HTML at client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, testing, automated-tests

I would like to front-end of my Django project. However, some DOMs specified in template and some DOMs generated in front-end JavaScript (mainly jQuery). At the same time, in Django template, some variables need to be queried from the database. I would like to know how to test whole front-end without setting the database. That is, just insert variables into template and test them at client side (i.e. load JavaScript as well, I mean). I know the Django support test cases on template and suggest using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) on client side, but I don't know how to combine them and apply in my scenario at ease. I prefer use python library if possible, because not all members of our project know hot to program JavaScript, but all suggestions are welcome still. To be specific, I want to test [this](https://github.com/NAL-i5K/genomics-workspace/blob/master/blast/static/blast/scripts/blast-multi.js) JavaScript file, which is loaded in [this](https://github.com/NAL-i5K/genomics-workspace/blob/master/blast/templates/blast/main.html) template. Therefore, 

`var dataset_list = {{ blastdb_list|safe }};
    var blastdb_type_counts = {{ blastdb_type_counts|jsonify }};`

Load the variable, but I want to insert some already known value and write test of that javascript. As you see, that JavaScript mainly use JQuery and manipulate some DOMs. Can someone give some directions and live examples if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selenium is often used for end-to-end tests. So that means using a database in the backend as well. If you want to test the front end in isolation, why involve django at all?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's because some DOMs are already on template, and I don't think it's a good idea without reusing the template. It seems that it's possible I rewrite a HTML for testing other JavaScript code. However, it's no sense to rewrite that. I think it's error prone during rewriting steps and I think there should be some methods for avoiding doing such error prone thing, maybe I am wrong. I know perhaps it's weird distributed DOMs in Django and JavaScript, but it's previous implementation and I am seeking a method to reuse them before rewrite them.

Comment: What do you mean by "some DOMs". The DOM is not plural. It's a web standard programming interface. https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: @HåkenLid I mean some HTML elements are in templates, some HTML elements are dynamically generated in JavaScript. I can't solely test JavaScript part. It's only part of HTML tags in our web, and it's bound on HTML tags defined in template.

Comment: You could create a different django view for testing that renders the same template with mock context data, without querying the database.

Comment: @HåkenLid Can you write a example for that? I am not sure what you mean. It will create new URLs, right? I need to comment them out when I want to deploy them?

Comment: There are many ways of doing that. Do not comment out stuff when deploying. That's bound to lead to a mess. Use different django settings files during testing, development and production. You could use a modified url router in testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !